# The type java.util.Comparator cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files

Tags: java, eclipse, compiler-errors

I am using Eclipse IDE, and I encountered this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
    The type java.util.Comparator cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files

    at project2.FeatureList.<init>(FeatureList.java:1)
    at project2.EveryPlaceHasAName.main(EveryPlaceHasAName.java:81)
```

```
package project2; //line error referenced by "at project2.FeatureList.<init>(FeatureList.java:1)"

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;

public class FeatureList extends ArrayList<Feature>{
    
    /**
     * Creates an empty FeatureList.
     */
    public FeatureList() {
    }

...
}
```

```
package project2;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.ArrayList;



public class EveryPlaceHasAName {
    
    public static void main( String[] args ) {

    ...

        FeatureList list = new FeatureList(); //line error referenced by "at project2.EveryPlaceHasAName.main(EveryPlaceHasAName.java:81)"
    
    ...

    }
}
```

This is the only error that is being displayed. Please help, I don't understand why it is not compiling. I'm fairly new to programming, so please explain how to solve it in a simple way.

Answer (score 1):

In your eclipse's preferences window, type `jre` in the filter box. The JRE(s) you have told eclipse about are listed here. Whichever one is enabled is broken. The answer will be in this dialog box; doublecheck that path, re-configure it, or point it at a proper JDK, etc.

Comment: Got it, thanks! Under Preferences I went to

Java -> Installed JREs -> Execution Environment

and selected the most current one (JavaSE-16) and ticked the compatible JRE on the right.